# R print function aligns tab differently on Windows

Tags: r

In an R 3.6.1 session on Windows, I wrote:

```r
> data.frame(tab = '\t')
  tab
1   \t
```

The `t` from the `\t` sticks out a bit. I had expected it to align nicely with the `tab` from the heading.

Curiously, this only happens with `\t`, but not with `\n`:

```r
> data.frame(tab = '\n')
  tab
1  \n
```

That one is nicely aligned, even though it is an escape sequence like `\t`.

The misalignment only happens on Windows (R 3.6.1), not on NetBSD (R 3.6.1) or [Linux](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/print) (R 3.4.0).

What is a possible explanation for this inconsistency?